# Calling web api via HTTPS from console application (Both are deployed in Windows Docker)

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-3.1

I have deployed .NET core 3.1 web API in Docker and configured SSL. Also deployed Angular application and Console application in Docker to interact with web API.

The Angular application works seamlessly. the only problem is with the console application (called Alerts). the console application is not able to call the web API.

I have tried below, but nothing worked. I am using `HttpClient`

```
https://172.18.0.5/api (Error: timeout) 
http://172.18.0.5/api (Error: timeout) 
http://backendservice/api (Error: Name or service not known)
https://backendservice/api (Error: Name or service not known)
```

> calling http://172.18.0.5/api worked from console application before SSL (without certificates)

My docker-compose.yml looks below-

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
        - '5432:5432'
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        POSTGRES_DB: mydb
  backendservice:
    build:  
      context: .  
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  
    image: mydockerhub/myapi
    ports:
      - "8082:443"
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8082
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=test
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/dev_cert.pfx
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d/https/:/https/
  alerts:
    build:  
      context: .  
      dockerfile: Alerts/Dockerfile 
    image: mydockerhub/myalerts
  frontend:
    image: mydockerhub/myfrontend
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

Comment: I guess that you should [configure a network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) to connect all services together

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, after inspecting both containers, found they share common `NetworkMode`